# How to setup logging in Tomcat for WebappClassLoader?

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j, classloader

I am trying to setup logging in Tomcat according to http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/logging.html.
I created file **Tomcat5\common\classes\log4j.properties**:

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, R 
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender 
log4j.appender.R.File=${catalina.home}/logs/tomcat.log 
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=500MB 
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=10 
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n

log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina.loader=DEBUG, C
log4j.appender.C=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender 
log4j.appender.C.File=${catalina.home}/logs/cl.log 
log4j.appender.C.MaxFileSize=500MB 
log4j.appender.C.MaxBackupIndex=10 
log4j.appender.C.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.C.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n
```

I would like to see traces from method **loadClass** of **org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader** class.
But there are only traces from **org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader**.

Can someone explain why there are no any traces from **WebappClassLoader** and how turn them on?

**UPDATE:**
isDebugEnabled  for WebappLoader returns true, but for WebappClassLoader returns false.
Why?

Comment: You've enabled `DEBUG`, not `TRACE`.

Comment: Yes. I would like to see traces from 
if (log.isDebugEnabled())
            log.debug("loadClass(" + name + ", " + resolve + ")");

Answer (score 0):

WebappClassLoader is initialized before Log4J is loaded.
So to setup logging in Tomcat for WebappClassLoader you need to add log4j.jar(and commons-logging.jar?) and loj4j.properties to classpath of JVM in wich Tomcat will be runnning.

Comment: the WebappClassLoader does not use log4j, but JULI, see e.g. http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina/7.0.0/org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappClassLoader.java/